# How to access variables declared outside d3.json request within it

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, d3.js, scope

I have a variable Params passed in as an argument to the makePlot function. I would like to access it within the d3.json request but it is coming up as undefined. See Below.

```
const makePlot = (Params) => {
  // Params defined here
  d3.json(`somedata.json`, (error, data) => {
  // Params not defined here
    data.forEach((d) => {
     d.Params.something = Number(d.Params.something);
     d.Params.somethingElse = Number(d.Params.somethingElse);
    }); 
};
```

Is there any way to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `Params` (without any prepending `d.`) is readily available within your inner function. This is called a [closure] https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/444255), normal javascript featgure.

**Just remove the `d.` before it.**

`d` is an entirely different variable, basically the first-level sub-elemens of your `data`, that you are iterating about. (most likely object properties resp. array members).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have put a debugger inside the json request and Params is undefined, which is quite confusing to me. I have Params after the d to access specific data from the json data.

Comment: remove the `d.`, then try the debugger again :) – the mean thing is, that variables only become a closure, if they do get used. Otherwise they are not around, in dev tools/debuggers.

Comment: I got it working now thanks for the advice. Totally forgot that the variables wouldn't show if they weren't used.